# Cannot initialize a vector of const char*/string array with an initializer-list on declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

Initially I started trying to initialize a vector of const char*[3] with an initilizer-list on declaration

```
vector<const char*[3]> v = { { "a", "b", "c" } };
```

And this gives the error

```
matrix must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

I thought it might be due to the const char*, although it seemed odd, and changed it into strings

```
vector<string[3]> v = { { "a", "b", "c" } };
```

But the error persists. I tried several combinations of braces to no avail. Is it actually possible to initialize this structure on declaration with an initializer-list?

Comment: What is the purpose of the vector? Do you want a single vector with three single string elements (i.e. `std::vector<std::string>`)? Or do you want a vector where each element is an array of three strings (i.e. `std::vector<std::array<std::string, 3>>`)?

Comment: I don't have an actual answer, but C arrays are second class citizens at best in the C and C++ type systems, so don't be surprised if most of the fancy stuff doesn't work with them. Try with `std::array`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I actually want the second option, a vector that contains arrays of 3 const char*/string elements. I was also thinking of using std::array (and have other solutions), but still wanting to know why this is not possible to do, or if it actually is possible and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If you can use `std::array` instead of `std::vector` it would compile `std::array<const char*[3], 1> v = { { "a", "b", "c" } };`

Comment: You forgot to specify what compiler and version gives that error. I have never seen an error like that. What is "matrix"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It fails to compile because [`std::vector` requires its `T` to be *CopyAssignable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Template_parameters). No matter its RHS, this statement wouldn't not compile:

```
vector<const char*[3]> v = { { "a", "b", "c" } }; // Error
```

just as this wouldn't compile either:

```
std::vector<const char*[3]> v;
const char* charPtrArr[3] { "a", "b", "c" };
v.push_back(charPtrArr); // Error
```

This is just a particular case of the fact that [*C-style arrays* are not assignable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230714/why-are-arrays-not-assignable-in-c-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), demonstrated in code directly by using `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable<const char*[3]>()); // Error
```

or more generally I guess:

```
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable<int[]>()); // Error
```

---

If you really wanted a `std::vector` of arrays of size 3 holding `char` pointers, then this is the error-free C++11 way to go about it:

```
vector<array<const char*, 3>> v = { { "a", "b", "c" }, { "d", "e", "f"} };
```

Comment: So, the problem is the same with string[3], because string is CopyAssignable, but string[3] is not. Yeah, that makes sense. I wrongly thought of it when I changed const char* into string. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Absolutely right, the *native array* itself is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is that C-style array can't be passed by copy or moved in function argument.
As a result this code will not work

```
vector<const char*[3]> v;
const char* item[3] { "a", "b", "c" };
v.push_back(item); // will not compile
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/LumvUzPnYWew7uMu
Basically this is the same problem, but initialization list is involved.

C++11 give you simple solution for your problem:

```
vector<array<const char*, 3>> v { { "a", "b", "c" }, { "d", "e", "f"} };
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/IHNoSrH9BWV1IUoQ